# getting started with ImageMagick

Tags: php, installation, imagemagick

I've heard ImageMagick is quite powerful, so I decided I'd learn how to use it.

I tried just pasting one of the examples on php.net to see if it worked, but it doesn't.  It says the imagick class doesn't exist.

My host is FatCow, and they do support it, but I don't know how to set things up.  I've looked around and I don't quite understand.

I asked FatCow, and I this is the answer:

> I have checked the issue and it seems
>   that Class 'Imagick' not found in the
>   script. Please add the ImageMagick
>   path /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick and
>   check the functionality. It should
>   work fine.

But I"m not quite sure what to do with that?

Also, I was wondering if anybody had links to some good resources to learn about ImageMagick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to edit your php.ini file and add:

```
include_path="/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick"
extension=imagick.so
```

This will tell php to look in that directory for additional libraries, and load the imagick extension.

Then, restart the server.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I added this to my php.ini, but seeing as it's shared hosting, I cannot restart the server. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to restart the machine - just apache. Do you have an ssh account?

Comment: hm. then maybe ask support to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can try phMagick:

http://www.francodacosta.com/blog/phmagick

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer.

I looked at it, and it seems like it's just a simplification of the imagick class?

I'm looking to actually learn to use imagick itself. And in either case, I'd still need to figure out what to do with:
/usr/local/lib/ImageMagick

because I can't access ImageMagick without it apparently :-(

Comment: I believe you're on a shared hosting environment.  Most hosting providers have imagemagick enabled and readily usable by PHP.  @cbrandolino's answer is correct however you won't be able to that since you're on a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Well, fatcow gives access to edit php.ini, but not to restart the server, of course. do you know if cbrandolino's answer is what the fatcow tech was suggesting I do?